# Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font width unknown for character 0x20

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, markdown, extrafont

I would like to use the free font [Lato](http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts) in `ggplot2` graphs since the remainder of my R markdown document is set in this font.

The font is installed on my system and available in the Font Book (*once only*).

All available fonts are loaded with the `extrafont` package and registered in the `extrafontdb`.

When I knit my markdown document as PDF, all text is correctly typeset in `Lato`. However, the plot labels of my ggPlots are not shown.

I also receive the following warning message:

`Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : font width unknown for character 0x20`

After embedding the fonts contained in the document with `extrafont::embed_fonts` the plot labels are shown for all figures using `Lato` as font, but

- the plot labels do not contain any spaces between words,
- any references (internal links, URLs, citations) do not work anymore.

An MWE including ggPlot figures with and without Lato as the font is provided below ([Lato is freely available here](http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/#download))
To embed the fonts afterwards one needs to run `embed_fonts("TestRmd.pdf", outfile="TestRmd_embedded.pdf")`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

### MWE:

````
---
title: "Embedding Fonts in PDF"
output: pdf_document
urlcolor: blue
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
```

### Plot with standard font {#standard}
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '30%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +     
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon")
```

### Load fonts and set font for ggplots globally
```{r include=FALSE}
# install.packages("extrafont") # see https://github.com/wch/extrafont/
library(extrafont)
# font_import()   # run once
loadfonts()       # loadfonts

# globally set ggplot2 theme and font ("Lato Light")
theme_set(theme_minimal(base_size=12, base_family="Lato Light"))
```

### Plot with newly set standard font (= Lato) {#lato}
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '30%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +     
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon")
```

### Plot with Impact font {#impact}
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '30%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16, family="Impact"))
```

### Run to embed fonts
```{r eval=FALSE, include=TRUE}
embed_fonts("TestRmd.pdf", outfile="TestRmd_embedded.pdf")
```

### Links test

Links test 1 (internal reference): [Headline standard](#standard)

Links test 2 (URL): [RStudio has become a Public Benefit Corporation](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/01/29/rstudio-pbc)
````

#### AddOn:

An even simpler problem but likely related to the same issue:

```
library(extrafont)
extrafont::font_import()
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + theme_minimal(base_size=10, base_family="Lato Light")
ggsave(p, filename = "iris.pdf")
```

The plot in the saved pdf does not contain any labels. Using `cairo_pdf` as recommend on several SO (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542302/ggplot-embedded-fonts-in-pdf), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501049/cannot-embed-ggplot2-r-fonts-in-pdf-with-ggsave)) sites does not help and results in the following error:

```
ggsave(p, filename = "iris.pdf", device = cairo_pdf)
# In dev(filename = filename, width = dim[1], height = dim[2], ...) :
#   failed to load cairo DLL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to make it work using `extrafont` but did not succeed. I am still not quite sure but I think it is a bug. Here is a solution using the package `showtext`:

````
---
title: "Embedding Fonts in PDF"
output: pdf_document
urlcolor: blue
---

```{r include=FALSE}
# notice the chunk option 'fig.showtext' that tells R to use the showtext 
# functionalities for each ne graphics device opened
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'pdf', cache = FALSE, fig.showtext = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)

font_add(family = "Lato", regular = "/Users/martin/Library/Fonts/Lato-Light.ttf") 
```


### Plot with newly set standard font (= Lato) {#lato}
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width = '100%'}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +     
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") + 
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + 
  ylab("Miles per Gallon") + 
  theme(text = element_text(family="Lato"))
```
````

[image]

Comment: thank you for your proposed solution using the `showtext` package, which works indeed! However, when I use this approach the document size of the knited PDF is much, much larger than if embedding the fonts (my 15mb report with extrafont turned into a gigantic 190mb file).

Comment: Could also not reduce the file size afterward using Adobe Acrobat Pro (in fact in increased to 230mb when I used the "Save as reduced size PDF" function...)

Comment: When I knit my code from above, the resulting file has a size of 141kb (Windows 10, knitr 1.28, MikTex 2.9). Whats the size when you knit my code?

Comment: @mavericks Even when I replicate the above chunk 6 times, the file size is 499kb without using Lato and 525kb when using it. The problem seems to be related to your document after all I guess.

Comment: when I knit your code, it has 142kb (MacOs 10.13.6, R 3.6.3, knitr 1.28, showtext 0.8-1, tinytex 0.23).

Comment: when I knit your code with normal font settings, i.e. without `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'pdf', cache = FALSE, fig.showtext = TRUE)` and `theme(text = element_text(family="Lato"))`, it has  72kb

Comment: I played around with my report and I have the impression that the large file size mainly stems from two reasons: 1) adding many layers to plots and 2) setting theme settings for plots individually.

Comment: I was able to reduce the file size from 190mb to 4mb as follows: 1) streamline plots by defining and setting a `ggtheme` globally, 2) try adding `geoms` at once if feasible, i.e. use `  geom_text(data = df_geom_text, aes(x = x_pos, y = y_pos, label = label))` to make several annotations in the plot. Nevertheless, the 20-page report is still much larger with `showtext` than without (640kb vs. 4mb)